# Getting a value from multiple tables on SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, e.g. ORDERS, each order has a receipt, but the receipts are separated in 3 tables. RECEIPT1, RECEIPT2 and RECEIPT3.

A column on table ORDERS called ORDER_TYPE will define in which of the RECEIPT tables the receipt is.

On my query I need a logic that does something like this: If ORDER_TYPE = 'C' my query gets a value from RECEIPT1, if it's equals 'X' from RECEIPT2 and etc.

I've already tried to use a left join on the 3 tables, but it returns triplicated rows and even if I group all of them there's still a chance of error.

Can anyone help me? Maybe cursors (which I dont know very much how to use)?

Comment: You should consider a view to merge the 3 tables.

Comment: `[RECEIPTn]` should probably be `[RECEIPT]` with an `n` column

Comment: It indeed should. The guy who structured the DB made some very bad decisions. I mean, the software is written in Delphi. If it was up to me I would throw everything away and use C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post the query you're attempting to use?

It sounds like adding to the ON statement should help. I'm guessing on the o.receipt = r1.receipt part. By adding the "o.order_type = 'c'" to the on statement, it will only join the records from that table when the order_type is what you need it to be.

```
SELECT *
FROM   ORDERS as o
   LEFT JOIN RECEIPT1 as R1 ON o.receipt = r1.receipt and o.order_type = 'c'
   LEFT JOIN RECEIPT2 as R2 ON o.receipt = r2.receipt and o.order_type = 'x'
   LEFT JOIN RECEIPT3 as R3 ON o.receipt = r3.receipt and o.order_type = '??'
```

The other answers are using unions, but correctly structured joins will be more efficient and easier to maintain.

This SELECT would return a query similar to the unions, assuming the column "amount" is what you want:

```
SELECT o.receipt, COALESCE(r1.amount, r2.amount, r3.amount) as amount
FROM   ORDERS as o
   LEFT JOIN RECEIPT1 as R1 ON o.receipt = r1.receipt and o.order_type = 'c'
   LEFT JOIN RECEIPT2 as R2 ON o.receipt = r2.receipt and o.order_type = 'x'
   LEFT JOIN RECEIPT3 as R3 ON o.receipt = r3.receipt and o.order_type = '??'
```

Comment: I tried this, doesnt work because it returns triplicated rows. But some people here reminded about UNION and now is working fine.

Comment: If you're looking for all of the values in a single column, I've updated my answer. If you're looking to remove multiple rows, you'll need a group by and an aggregate on the columns. If you were getting multiple rows but are not when you sue a union, be aware that unions are distinct, so you could be losing data you don't mean to (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/).

Comment: I used the UNION and it worked fine, because the tables have similar structure. I could use group by, but the way the tables were made i could have some issues. I mean, your answer is fine, the problem is the way the tables were made. It's a very badly designed software.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad design just asking for trouble :)

Use three different queries with a union. Not real queries below but you should get the basic idea.

```
select columns from orders,receipt1 where <joins and filters> and order_type = 'C'
union
select columns from orders,receipt2 where <joins and filters> and order_type = 'X'
union
etc etc
```

Comment: It is a bad design indeed. Actualy, I just now working on this project because the former developer left the country.

Comment: Why not use a case statement instead? Case Statement could be more efficient than union in this scenario. Also, `UNION ALL` has less overhead than `UNION`.

Comment: UNION ALL would triplicate the rows, because of that cartesian thing it does, and CASE is used inside the select right? I think it wouldnt fit because my problem is related to accessing different tables depending on the value of the column.

Comment: UNION ALL "might" duplicate the rows if you have orders that link to multiple receipt tables (regardless of the order_type). If you don't then it should work fine. How much faster it is really depends on how much data is returned by each select. If you have a huge dataset then UNION ALL will skip a sorting/unique step. If the dataset is small then you might save a few ms.

Answer (score 1):

We have to adapt it a little on your needings, but the base could be this

```
SELECT ...
FROM Orders o INNER JOIN Receipt1 R1 ON o.XXX = R1.XXX
WHERE o.ORDER_TYPE = 'C'
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM Orders o INNER JOIN Receipt2 R2 ON o.XXX = R2.XXX
WHERE o.ORDER_TYPE = 'X'
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM Orders o INNER JOIN Receipt3 R3 ON o.XXX = R3.XXX
WHERE o.ORDER_TYPE = 'Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the columns are the same in RECEIPT1, RECEIPT2 and RECEIPT3. (otherwise, change the R.* to the explicit columns that are common to the 3 RECEIPT tables)

```
(SELECT ORDERS.*, R.* FROM ORDERS
 INNER JOIN RECEIPT1 R ON ORDERS.receipt_id=R.id
 WHERE ORDERS.ORDER_TYPE='C')
UNION
(SELECT ORDERS.*, R.* FROM ORDERS
 INNER JOIN RECEIPT2 R ON ORDERS.receipt_id=R.id
 WHERE ORDERS.ORDER_TYPE='X')
UNION
(SELECT ORDERS.*, R.* FROM ORDERS
 INNER JOIN RECEIPT3 R ON ORDERS.receipt_id=R.id
 WHERE ORDERS.ORDER_TYPE='Z')
```

Comment: I totaly forgot about union! That's exactly what I needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to merge the receipts by order type, then join against the order type you associate to each receipt table. This keeps a simple join against the ORDERS table and let's you pick any of the fields from the matching RECEIPTn table.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        'C' AS ORDER_TYPE,
        *
    FROM RECEIPT1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        'X' AS ORDER_TYPE,
        *
    FROM RECEIPT2
    -- And so on
)
SELECT *
FROM ORDERS O
    INNER JOIN CTE R
        ON R.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID -- Whatever FK is
            AND R.ORDER_TYPE = O.ORDER_TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any table structure, and if I understand your issue correctly, you could use `CASE` statement to get your values based on order_type like this:

```
SELECT o.orderid
    ,CASE 
        WHEN o.order_type = 'C'
            THEN r1.receipt_value
        WHEN o.order_type = 'X'
            THEN r2.receipt_value
        ELSE r3.receipt_value
        END AS receipt_value
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN receipt1 r1 ON o.receiptid = r1.id
LEFT JOIN receipt2 r2 ON o.receiptid = r2.id
LEFT JOIN receipt3 r3 ON o.receiptid = r3.id
```

Comment: This should work if you change the INNER to OUTER joins. If there aren't entries in the various receipt tables for all of the orders (doesn't seem like it) then you will not get the proper rows (if any). The other downside for using case is when you want to get 20 columns back instead of just 1. It is just a lot more code in the select compared to a simple union

Comment: @TheMadDBA  You are absolutely right about the join. Thanks!